# Internet Explorer Drop down border

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Is there a way to hide the border of a drop down menu in IE (to make it look flat, blend into the background)?  In Firefox it's simple enough to just set the border to 0px, but IE still renders a border even if you set the border to 0px.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't possible in IE. They don't allow styling of the drop-down component of a list, except for the text inside it (ie. red text).

IE actually uses a Windows-level control, not a browser-based one, so it is rather limited.

**Edit**:  When this post was originally made, a stable version of IE8 wasn't released yet.  According to comments, IE8 supports border styling.  However, even ~2 years after IE8's release, you still shouldn't count on all of your users having IE8+.

Comment: Not true, IE8+ handles border styling if you are in standards mode (you have set a modern DOCTYPE).

Answer (score 0):

I recently saw some tool kits fly the actual dropdown out 5000 pixels, replace it with a custom control, and use javascript to connect the 2 controls.

Answer (score -1):

IE8 supports changing a drop down`s border, but IE6 doesn't.